# My PowerAutomate Flow doesn't recognize a SharePoint Yes/No Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, yes-no-field, boolean-field

I have a flow that is triggered by updates to a SharePoint list. One of the columns in that list is a Yes/No column. When I try to check the value of that column, PowerAutomate acts as if this column does not exist. Is this a known bug, or is there something I need to do as a workaround?

Comment: Check the solution given [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Flow-fails-on-Yes-No-column-Big-Flow/td-p/35116) and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this as I had the same problem. Here is a workaround.

1. Initialize string variable (let's call it Var_YesNo)
2. Create a Condition, in the left pane you can now select Yes/No columns, so select it. In the right pane from Dynamic Content select Expression: True.
3. Now set you Var_YesNo, Yes if yes, No if no.
4. No use Var_YesNo where you need to use the column.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a condition on Yes/No column in basic(default) flow design view it generates the advanced function something like:

```
@equals(triggerBody()?['YesNoColumn'], 'true')
```

And the problem with this is that it checks for a string `'true'`, instead of a boolean value for `true`. So Change the function to:

```
@equals(triggerBody()?['YesNoColumn'], true)
```

This should solve the issue as now it checks for actual boolean true instead of a string 'true'.

**Reference**: [Flow fails on Yes/No column (Big Flow)](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Flow-fails-on-Yes-No-column-Big-Flow/td-p/35116)

Comment: This is not the problem I'm having. When I try to select the Yes/No column in the first term of the condition, don't have it showing up in the list of columns from my trigger. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @ScottDavis This is strange...Did you resolve this issue? If you are still facing this issue, can you please try removing and adding trigger again? Or try creating another flow and check if it works in another flow.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows to check Conditional Yes/No Column Value in flow:

[image]

Reference:

[https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-check-condition-yesno-column-value-in-flow#:~:text=Add%20a%20condition%20action%20in,That's%20it](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-check-condition-yesno-column-value-in-flow#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20condition%20action%20in,That%27s%20it).

Comment: This is not the problem I'm having. When I try to select the Yes/No column in the first term of the condition, don't have it showing up in the list of columns from my trigger. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: If possible, could you please provide more information about your issue, such as screenshoot.

Comment: @ScottDavis - might be a problem where maybe you created the flow before you created the field, were in the flow, you created the field on the list, and so you have to go out of the flow's designer mode, and back in, and then you can see it? I have a Yes/No field on my list and I see it and I can use it in the Dynamic Content for whatever I create.

Answer (score 0):

Phrasing of the question seems odd - are you able to see the field in the Dynamic context at all? Or just not the value? So here are my takes on this question and answers:

- If you cannot load the field, it might be a problem where maybe you created the flow before you created the field, but after the list was there. You were in the flow, you created the field on the list, and so you have to go out of the flow's designer mode, and back in, and then you should see the field to be able to add it wherever you are trying to - in a Condition, Variable value, whatever.
- If you can load the field, but cannot get a value when you run it, try this:

Create a variable, "MyVar", as a String and add your field directly to it from the Dynamic context. If you were to hover over it, it would look like: `triggerOutputs()?['body/MyYesNoField']`

You could even put that into the Expression and update the value of the variable with it if you like - just update the `MyYesNoField` with the internal name of your field.

When you test that value in a Condition, you would say:

```
MyVar is equal to True
```

Where "MyVar" is that variable you created earlier and is represented like this, if you used the Expression Builder:

```
variables('MyVar')
```

Obviously, if you want to test for a false condition instead, use `False`.

Because the variable is a String variable, use just straight typing into the box. No Expression Builder, no `bool(true)`, just straight typing of the value directly, with a capital first letter.

HTH!